# How can I resize an Android UI element during onLayout?

Tags: android, layout, view, measure

I have a button class based on a `LinearLayout` that contains two `TextView`s, and I want the button always to be square (which I'm doing using `onMeasure()`), and the upper of the `TextView`s to resize automatically to fit the button.  I want the lower `TextView` to have fixed-size text, so it looks roughly like

```
|---------|
|         |
|  1 8 0  |
|         |
|   foo   |
|---------|
```

with "180" being as large as possible in the available space.

I'm calling a function in `onLayout()` called `adjustTextSize()`:

```
private void adjustTextSize() {

    float height = mHeight - mTitleView.getMeasuredHeight() - 4 * mPadding - getPaddingTop() - getPaddingBottom(); //title text view

    int numberheight = (int) (height * 0.75);
    int extravertpadding = 0;//(int) (height * 0.125);

    mTitleView.setPadding(mPadding, 0, mPadding, mPadding);

    mNumberView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, numberheight);
    mNumberView.setPadding(mPadding, mPadding + extravertpadding, mPadding, mPadding + extravertpadding);

    if(mNumberView.getMeasuredWidth() > mWidth) {
        float reduction = mWidth / mNumberView.getMeasuredWidth();
        extravertpadding = (int) ((numberheight - height*reduction) / 2);
        numberheight = (int) (height*reduction);
        mNumberView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, numberheight);
        mNumberView.setPadding(mPadding, mPadding + extravertpadding, mPadding, mPadding + extravertpadding);
    }

    mNumberView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, numberheight);
    mNumberView.setPadding(mPadding, mPadding + extravertpadding, mPadding, mPadding + extravertpadding);

}
```

`mWidth` and `mHeight` are set in `onLayout()`.

However, I have two initial problems: firstly, setting the text size to a certain pixel value makes the `View` somewhat *bigger* than the pixel value.  I want to work out how large to set the text height to fit the available space; three quarters seems to work OK but I would rather have an exact value.

The second problem is that the value of `getMeasuredWidth()` seems not to be changing after I've changed the text size.  Why not?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to part 2:

It's necessary to call

```
mNumberView.measure(
    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
);
```

to tell the system to measure the view as though there were no constraints on its size.  After this has been called you can find out how large the view *would* be if space were no object and scale it down accordingly.